# Error: "Cannot add children to a ResourceDictionary when the Source property is set."

Tags: c#, xaml, resources, styles, global

I tried to add a global style that would be applied to all my control in my app.

I added my style in app.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="SimulatorUi.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"></Setter>
        </Style>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

It work fine in a test app. But when I add the style to my real app, I receive a compiler error:
"Cannot add children to a ResourceDictionary when the Source property is set.".

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Any helps would be appreciate?

Note1:
I can add a resource dictionary without problem:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfAppTestResource.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Note 2: (original question related only)
My app use "Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase" to ensure to run only a single instance. I was missing the "InitializeComponent()" before the _application.Run() which is essential. I fixed one problem, but I still have my initial problem and my test using SingleInstance pattern does work fine. Only my real app does fail to run properly.

Code used for Single Instance:

```
namespace WpfApplication1.SingleInstanceApp
{
    public class SingleInstanceManager : Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase
    {
        private App _application;
        private System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<string> _commandLine;

        private static readonly SingleInstanceManager _instance = new SingleInstanceManager();

        private SingleInstanceManager()
        {
            IsSingleInstance = true;
        }

        public static SingleInstanceManager Instance
        {
            get { return _instance; }
        }

        protected override bool OnStartup(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            // First time _application is launched
            _commandLine = eventArgs.CommandLine;

            _application = new App();

            // Missing line in original code which I had to adapt.
            // _application.InitializeComponent();
            if (_contentLoaded)
            {
                return false;
            }
            _contentLoaded = true;

            // this.StartupUri = new System.Uri("MainWindow.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);
            System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/" + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ";component/app.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);
            System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(_application, resourceLocater);

            _application.Run();
            return false;
        }

        protected override void OnStartupNextInstance(StartupNextInstanceEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            // Subsequent launches
            base.OnStartupNextInstance(eventArgs);
            _commandLine = eventArgs.CommandLine;
            _application.Activate();
        }
    }
}


namespace WpfApplication1.SingleInstanceApp
{
    public class EntryPoint
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SingleInstanceManager manager = SingleInstanceManager.Instance;
            manager.Run(args);
        }
    }
}


namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        // ******************************************************************
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            // AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
            // TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException;

            base.OnStartup(e);
            this.MainWindow = new MainWindow();
            MainWindow.Show();
        }

        // ******************************************************************
        public void Activate()
        {
            MainWindow.Activate();
        }

        // ******************************************************************
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed part of the problem by adding code equivalent of _application.InitializeComponent(); in OnStartup of SingleInstanceManager.
After I fixed the bug in OnStartup, the problem was still there.

I restarted Visual Studio and the the problem disapeared !!!   Grrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr!!!

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that restarting Visual Studio fixes the issue.

Comment: Confirming that this still occurs in VS2015.

Comment: VS2015, restarting Visual Studio solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I did not even have to restart visual studio. I cut and pasted my UserControl.Resources right above my x:Code and the error went away. It was right below it before.

Comment: Thanks. I will let my answer like it is until you get 2 upvotes. If you have them. I will accept your answer instead because it is easier (just let me know). But I prefer to wait and see if other could fix their problems the same way you did. I can't reproduce this issue to verify if it always fixes the issue.